# How to develop my own user authentification model in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I created a ASP MVC project, as you may know it's not a blank one, some sample pages and account model already written inside it.

```
       [Authorize]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            /*some logic here*/
            return View();
        }
```

Then I added the annotation `[Authorize]` before my action, it will automatically use their own default user model and directed to their Signup page, but how can I configure that to my own user model? Where can I set it up?

Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Which model are you looking to change?  By default the project may create things like a Login model, a Registration model, etc.  They're mainly view models for the pages themselves and exist in the Models folder (probably in a file called `AccountModels.cs`).  You can edit those directly.  Or are you trying to customize something else about the authentication system?

Comment: @David Say I've created my own user model based on a Server SQL table, how can I build up my own authentication system?(like creating login and signup page)

Comment: You can customize the login and signup pages any way you'd like, and customize their associated view models accordingly.  Building your own authentication system sounds like a lot more than what you actually want to do.  It sounds like maybe what you want is to create a custom MembershipProvider (and perhaps RoleProvider).  Someone helped me with that a while back as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16843880/a-custom-membership-provider-without-a-database  The provider simply connects the authentication system with your custom backing data.