# Testing user registration in a brand new MVC 4 internet project with specflow and selenium webdriver

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, selenium-webdriver, membership-provider, specflow

I have been setting up a new Specflow project, using selenium webdriver to automate a new MVC 4 application. I have so far made no changes to the MVC application. The aim of this project is to test out the ATDD development. As such the first use cases I have implemented have been to test the registration page that comes set up with the new MVC 4 application. I have been looking for a way to isolate my tests from each other from a data perspective, and I have found this:

http://jamesheppinstall.wordpress.com/2012/12/29/managing-specflow-acceptance-test-data-with-entity-framework/

However, my application doesn’t yet have a data context. As I have only been using the registration page, the membership provider has dealt with the database stuff. 
How can I clear down the database (or the users table) before each test when the only data access in my application is via the WebSecurity class? I need to be able to make this work both on my local machine and on my CI server.

Comment: In which case, what's wrong with using standard SQL using ADO.NET?

Comment: Well I was hoping someone would have a really nice solution already.

Comment: Would it not be better to avoid the database? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16843880/a-custom-membership-provider-without-a-database?rq=1